# XTR Di2 front derailleur mount for Cannondale Scalpel 29r

Tags: cannondale, shimano-di2, derailleur-front

Is there an adapter to mount a XTR Di2 front derailleur on a Cannondale Cannondale Scalpel 29r?
[picture of stock mount](http://www.bikeradar.com/news/article/sea-otter-2011-cannondales-new-scalpel-29-29915/)

Images from BikeRadar:

[image] [image]

Comment: I've embedded the images and removed the tracker link you used. I hope that's ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done a bit of looking about and it looks like your frame takes an E-Type direct mount. Since the new XTR Di2 front mech uses a modular mounting system you'd simply buy the E-Type mount, bolt it to the frame and attach the FD to this.

[image: Cannondale Scalpel]

I've gone off the photo above to determine FD mount type. Looks like the E-Type to me, so the mount [here](http://www.chainreactioncycles.com/shimano-xtr-di2-front-mech-mount-adaptor/rp-prod124577?gs=1&gclid=CJmD_qrmrMoCFYpsGwodGkELuA&gclsrc=aw.ds) should be all you need. The picture on Chain Reaction Cycles doesn't show the correct mount. It should look like the image below!

[image]

Comment: No problem! Happy to help :-)